# Position not working in Firefox?

Tags: css, firefox

Okay, so I have a slider (using bx-slider).

In chrome, the slider looks perfect. However, in Firefox, the text overlay doesn't show. If you right click and inspect the element, you will see the following css setting:

```
.featuresGrid ul li .summary {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

If I temporarily disable the `position: absolute`, then re-enable it, the text overlays suddenly work perfectly. Why are they broken on initial page load? Its broken in IE as well btw.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
.featuresGrid .featuresOuter {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #000;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.featuresOuter .bx-wrapper {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.featuresOuter .bx-viewport {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
}
.featuresOuter .bx-viewport > .heightFix {
  width: auto;
  position: relative;
}
.featuresOuter .heightFix {
  height: 200px;
}
.featuresOuter ul li {
  list-style: outside none none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  width: 1158px;
}
.featuresGrid ul li a {
  position: relative;
}
.featuresGrid ul li .summary {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
}
```

```html
<div class="section featuresGrid" id="featuresGrid">
  <div class="featuresOuter">
    <div class="bx-wrapper">
      <div class="bx-viewport">
        <ul class="heightFix">
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <div class="heightFix">
                <div class="summary">
                  <div class="title">SoulCast #34: The GloomyCast</div>
                  <div class="excerpt">"GloomyCast" kind of sounds like a bad weather report, doesn't it? In any case, a big ring made of deathblades seems a bit dangerous for the user, if you ask me, but warning labels aren't going to keep Tira down! This episode SaltFace_GA
                    was kind enough to come on to the podcast and talk some Tira strats. I had to fight a little technical difficulty, but I hope you still enjoy! Only a couple of characters left after this! 8104 YouTube channel:...</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself, instead of linking the full page.

Comment: Thats the problem Oriol... I dont KNOW what code is causing the issue. According to the code, there is no issue... which I explained in the OP.

Comment: Of course. Knowing which is the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem requires some work. You can't expect people to do that hard work for you for free.

Comment: What I'm saying is I have no possible understand of how the issue COULD be happening. Because firefox works perfectly fine if the element is disabled, then re-enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are positioning `.summary` relatively to an anchor, which is an inline element. This can be problematic.

Then, you can add

```css
.featuresGrid ul > li > a {
  display: block;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
.featuresGrid .featuresOuter {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #000;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.featuresOuter .bx-wrapper {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.featuresOuter .bx-viewport {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
}
.featuresOuter .bx-viewport > .heightFix {
  width: auto;
  position: relative;
}
.featuresOuter .heightFix {
  height: 200px;
}
.featuresOuter ul li {
  list-style: outside none none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  width: 1158px;
}
.featuresGrid ul li a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
.featuresGrid ul li .summary {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
}
```

```html
<div class="section featuresGrid" id="featuresGrid">
  <div class="featuresOuter">
    <div class="bx-wrapper">
      <div class="bx-viewport">
        <ul class="heightFix">
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <div class="heightFix">
                <div class="summary">
                  <div class="title">SoulCast #34: The GloomyCast</div>
                  <div class="excerpt">"GloomyCast" kind of sounds like a bad weather report, doesn't it? In any case, a big ring made of deathblades seems a bit dangerous for the user, if you ask me, but warning labels aren't going to keep Tira down! This episode SaltFace_GA
                    was kind enough to come on to the podcast and talk some Tira strats. I had to fight a little technical difficulty, but I hope you still enjoy! Only a couple of characters left after this! 8104 YouTube channel:...</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can position `.summary` relatively to `.heightFix`:

```css
.featuresOuter .heightFix {
  position: relative;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
.featuresGrid .featuresOuter {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #000;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.featuresOuter .bx-wrapper {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.featuresOuter .bx-viewport {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
}
.featuresOuter .heightFix {
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
.featuresOuter ul li {
  list-style: outside none none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  width: 1158px;
}
.featuresGrid ul li a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
.featuresGrid ul li .summary {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
}
```

```html
<div class="section featuresGrid" id="featuresGrid">
  <div class="featuresOuter">
    <div class="bx-wrapper">
      <div class="bx-viewport">
        <ul class="heightFix">
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <div class="heightFix">
                <div class="summary">
                  <div class="title">SoulCast #34: The GloomyCast</div>
                  <div class="excerpt">"GloomyCast" kind of sounds like a bad weather report, doesn't it? In any case, a big ring made of deathblades seems a bit dangerous for the user, if you ask me, but warning labels aren't going to keep Tira down! This episode SaltFace_GA
                    was kind enough to come on to the podcast and talk some Tira strats. I had to fight a little technical difficulty, but I hope you still enjoy! Only a couple of characters left after this! 8104 YouTube channel:...</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```